# git add a commit early and have its changes cascade forward?

Tags: git, tfs, commit

We are trying to move from TFS to git using git-tfs.
After several botched attempts, it seems that all of the tfs moved successfully, save for one commit - the first one in the branch.

This caused a cascade effect, where each next commit didn't have these files either, because I assume TFS stores patches and not snapshots.

Is there a way in git, to add this commit at the beginning, and rewrite the history of the next commits to include those files?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. A rebase is pretty simple:

Make sure that the missing commit is committed in your repo so there is a sha id for it. Checkout the head of the branch which is missing the commit and then rebase.

```
git rebase <sha for missing commit>
```

Perhaps also take a look at `git rebase --interactive`

Comment: That commit should be the first one in the branch, so should I checkout the branch head or the current first commit in the branch?

Comment: @WimpyToes You should checkout the branch head. That is you just make sure to have the entire new branch checked out, then do the rebase. That will replay all of the branch on top of the lost commit. If there are no merge issues you will end up with the lost commit first, then all of the rest.

Comment: What about branches to main? will they also be fixed?

Comment: Other branches will not be fixed automatically, you would need to rebase those using the same method.